# Tratamento de erros no DataGridTextColumn

Tags: c#, datagridview

Dentro de uma DataGridView tenho um campo de texto e já tentei de tudo mas não consigo validá-lo. Exemplo:

1 - Exste as colunas com o nome do produto e preço.
2 - Existe estes DataGridTextColumn que o usuário digita a quantidade de produtos.
3 - Ao clicar em um Botão na grid ele faz a venda do produto.

Mas como evitar que o usuário não digite nada neste campo? Se o usuário deixar o campo em branco ele dá erro obviamente. Tentei de várias formas, mas em todos os exemplos ele me retorna um erro e o sistema para.

Segue o código usado quando

```
private void dv_consulta_produtos_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    linha_atual = int.Parse(e.RowIndex.ToString());
    idprod = dv_consulta_produtos["idprodData", linha_atual].Value.ToString();
    nome_produto = dv_consulta_produtos["nomeData", linha_atual].Value.ToString();
    cod_produto = dv_consulta_produtos["codprodutoData",linha_atual].Value.ToString();
    modelo = dv_consulta_produtos["modeloData", linha_atual].Value.ToString();
    marca = dv_consulta_produtos["marcaData", linha_atual].Value.ToString();
    ncm = dv_consulta_produtos["ncmData", linha_atual].Value.ToString();
    qtd = dv_consulta_produtos["qtd1", linha_atual].Value.ToString();

    **//AQUI o Botao vender é acionado**    
    if (dv_consulta_produtos.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "bt_vender")
    {
        **// AQUI tentei de tudo mas não consigo fazer funcionar o tratamento de valor nulo**
        if (qtdDataGridViewTextBoxColumn == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Quantidade não pode ser nulo");
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            MySqlConnection conn2 = conexao.obterConexao();
            MySqlCommand comando_cadastro = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO vendas_itens (N_OS, IDPROD, COD_PRODUTO, NOME, MODELO, MARCA, NCM, QTD)" +
            "VALUES('" + n_os + "','" + idprod + "', '" + cod_produto + "', '" + nome_produto + "', '" + modelo + "' , '" + marca + "', '" + ncm + "', '" + qtd + "')", conn2);
            comando_cadastro.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Produto " + nome_produto + " inserido com sucesso");
            conexao.fechaConexao();
        }
    }
}
```

Foram tentadas os tratamentos

```
qtd = dv_consulta_produtos["qtd1", linha_atual].Value.ToString();
if (qtd =="" || qtd == "0")
{
    MessageBox.Show("Quantidade não pode ser nulo");
    return;
}
```

Comment: Você deve postar o seu código, explicar as maneiras que você já tentou e não deu certo, falta informação na sua pergunta.

Comment: Olá. Editei e coloquei o código.

Comment: você já tentou tipo if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(qtdDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.ToString()))

Comment: qual mensagem aparece quando você tenta as tratativas? é algum erro? não entra nos ifs?

Comment: Oi Paulo. Tudo bem? Vou fazer esse teste que me indicou! O erro que aparece é
System.NullReferenceException: 'Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto.'

Comment: @João Paulo Amorim. Boa noite. Tentei o que me indicou e continuo com o mesmo defeito. Quando coloco um valor dentro do DataGridViewTextBoxColumn como 1 por exemplo o código funciona, quando não há nada ele para. e aparece

Ocorreu uma exceção sem tratamento do tipo "System.NullReferenceException" em SYSFOCO2.exe
Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto.

Comment: entendi, no caso que da esse erro vc está usando essa condição if (qtd =="" || qtd == "0") ? se sim, tente deste modo if (qtd == null || qtd =="" || qtd == "0")

Comment: @JoãoPauloAmorim. O erro permanece. Acredito que devo estar errando em algo na estrutura inteira. Vou tentar refazer linha por linha e caso tenha alguma resposta eu coloco aqui! Obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: Sim, verifique exatamente aonde está estourando o erro

Answer (score 0):

Após buscar algumas alternativas percebi que o meu código não estava percorrendo a coluna textbox do Datagrid. Então recriei o código e solucionei o problema.

**O código anterior**

```
if (dv_consulta_produtos.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "bt_vender")
{
    **// AQUI tentei de tudo mas não consigo fazer funcionar o tratamento de valor nulo**
    if (qtdDataGridViewTextBoxColumn == null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Quantidade não pode ser nulo");
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        MySqlConnection conn2 = conexao.obterConexao();
        MySqlCommand comando_cadastro = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO vendas_itens (N_OS, IDPROD, COD_PRODUTO, NOME, MODELO, MARCA, NCM, QTD)" +
        "VALUES('" + n_os + "','" + idprod + "', '" + cod_produto + "', '" + nome_produto + "', '" + modelo + "' , '" + marca + "', '" + ncm + "', '" + qtd + "')", conn2);
        comando_cadastro.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Produto " + nome_produto + " inserido com sucesso");
        conexao.fechaConexao();
    }
}
```

**O código corrigido**

```
        private void dv_consulta_produtos_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        //CRIANDO A VARIAVEL PARA BUSCAR O BOTÃO
        var botao = (DataGridView)sender;
        if (botao.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewButtonColumn &&
    e.RowIndex >= 0)
        {
            // a minha DataGridTextBox tem valor 1 então percorro as linhas e verifico
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dv_consulta_produtos.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value as string))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("NAO PODE FICAR NULO");
            }
            else
            {
                // SE O DataGridTextBox não estiver em branco então executa o comando
                MySqlConnection conn2 = conexao.obterConexao();
                MySqlCommand comando_cadastro = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO vendas_itens (N_OS, IDPROD, COD_PRODUTO, NOME, MODELO, MARCA, NCM, QTD)" +
                "VALUES('" + n_os + "','" + idprod + "', '" + cod_produto + "', '" + nome_produto + "', '" + modelo + "' , '" + marca + "', '" + ncm + "', '" + qtd + "')", conn2);
                comando_cadastro.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Produto " + nome_produto + " inserido com sucesso");
                conexao.fechaConexao();

            }
        }
```